# std::unique merge

Tags: c++, algorithm

I'm using `std::unique` to take merge clusters in a float vector using an equals method with large epsilon. The problem is it take runs like 1 and turns them to 2.
While I want it to merge them like using average on "equal" points, turn them into 3.

```
(1) ...               .      ....    .....
(2) .                 .      .       .
(3)  .                .       .        .
```

How can I do this using the C++ standard library?

Comment: What is the format of the data?  It can't just be `std::vector<float>` or you'd lose the positioning.  Unless I misunderstand you.

Comment: @MooingDuck: it is, the value is the position. the first one is like 1,2,3,20,25,26,27,28,35,36,37,38,39.

Comment: Are "runs" always sequential?

Comment: I reckon it would be easier to just write the algorithm yourself rather than create some super predicate which will average things for you.

Comment: `unique` is always going to keep the first of the equivalent values. The requirements are highly specific. You need to roll your own function.

Comment: I get the feeling that you'll need to write your own code for this. Otherwise, you'll need someplace, either the elements of your collection, or an additional data structure, to store the 'sum' and 'count' of each run that you're going to average out. You would then have to bake processing that into the predicate you pass in, and ensure that it's robust to any legitimate implementation of `std::unique`.

Comment: "an equals method with large epsilon" is not an equivalence relation, so it's invalid to use it with `std::unique` at all.

Answer (score 2):

No, there's no standard algorithm that can do what you want.  However, it's not incredibly complicated.  I attempted to make minimal assumptions about the iterators, so this should work with any forward input iterator.

```
#include <iostream>

template<class initer, class outiter, class predicate>
outiter average_runs(initer begin, initer end, outiter out, predicate pred) {
    //quit if no range
    if (begin == end)
        return out;
    initer endrun = begin; 
    do {
        //find end of run
        while(endrun+1 != end && pred(*endrun,*(endrun+1)))
            ++endrun;
        //move "begin" to the middle
        std::advance(begin, std::distance(begin,endrun)/2);
        //output the result
        *out++ = *begin;
        //start next run
        begin = ++endrun;
    } while(endrun != end);
    return out;
}

bool intclose(int l, int r) 
{ return r-l <= 1;}
int main() {
    int array[13] = {1,2,3,20,25,26,27,28,35,36,37,38,39};
    int output[13] = {};
    int* end = average_runs((int*)array, array+13, (int*)output, &intclose);
    for(int* c = output; c<end; ++c)
        std::cout << *c << ' ';
    return 0;
}
//displays: 2 20 26 37
```

Comment: The expression `(endrun-begin)` is not guaranteed for a forward iterator.

Comment: Also I can't find a guarantee that if `fwditer a=b; b++; a++;` that `a` and `b` "point" to the same "location".  This means that istream iterators will probably fail miserably on this and similar algorithms.

Comment: It would be truly marvellous if you could find the midpoint of a series without ever knowing what the next number is going to be, don't you think? ;)

Comment: If wishes were horses I would have wings!  (or something)